# What is the best way to download images using multithreading ?

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm trying to download image from web. For single image I downloaded successfully. But I want to download more images with multithreading. Any tutorials or leads regarding this will be helpful to me.

Comment: So you did a search with Google and weren't able to find anything?

Comment: [Lazy Loading](http://stackoverflow.com/q/541966/3264399) is the best

Answer (score 1):

As for me, simplest way to do to this - use some third-party library with caching system and post-processing. Most popular is:
1) [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) from Square team
2) [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) works fine and has a lot of options